# F# library that subclasses a class from a C# library

Tags: c#, .net-core, f#, solution, c#-to-f#

I want to convert the C# classes in my console app to F#, one at a time.  With stunning help from Co-pilot, I got one class done.  But I can’t build with it.  So I made a tiny test solution, to investigate.  I’m using
.NET 7.0 SDK (v7.0.201)

The C# compiler complains:

- Program.cs(7, 14): [CS0712] Cannot create an instance of the static class 'Class2'
- Program.cs(7, 1): [CS0723] Cannot declare a variable of static type 'Class2'
- Program.cs(8, 29): [CS1061] 'Class2' does not contain a definition for 'Greeting' and no accessible extension method 'Greeting' accepting a first argument of type 'Class2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Program.cs(8, 49): [CS1061] 'Class2' does not contain a definition for 'Number' and no accessible extension method 'Number' accepting a first argument of type 'Class2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I’m just learning how to write a class in F#, and I can’t see how to fix this.

```
#!/bin/bash

dotnet new sln 

dotnet new console -o Console
dotnet new classlib -o LibraryC 
dotnet new classlib -lang "F#" -o LibraryF

dotnet sln add Console/Console.csproj 
dotnet sln add LibraryC/LibraryC.csproj  
dotnet sln add LibraryF/LibraryF.fsproj 

dotnet add LibraryF reference LibraryC
dotnet add Console  reference LibraryF

cat << 'EOT' > LibraryC/Class1.cs
namespace LibraryC;

public class Class1 {

  public virtual int Number => 17;

  public virtual string Greeting() => "Hello";

}
EOT

cat << 'EOT' > LibraryF/Library.fs
namespace LibraryF

open LibraryC

module Class2 =   // ANSWER: Remove this.

  type Class2() =     
    inherit Class1()
    
    member this.Junk() = "not static"
      
    override this.Number = 42

    override this.Greeting() =
      let fromBase = base.Greeting()
      $"{fromBase} from Class2 {this.Number}"
EOT

cat << 'EOT' > Console/Program.cs
using LibraryC;
using LibraryF;

var class1 = new Class1();
Console.WriteLine($"{class1.Greeting()} {class1.Number}");

var class2 = new Class2();
Console.WriteLine($"{class2.Greeting()} {class2.Number}");
EOT
```

I wrote the above script by hand.  This way of exporting a solution seems very useful, so I opened an issue for a [dotnet command to export a .sln file as a sequence of dotnet commands](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/37554).

Comment: I don't know F# but it struck my eye that there's a "module" called "Class2" _and_ a type called "Class2". Doesn't feel like a good idea? Or is that how it works in F#? Just guessing here.

Comment: Also, the compiler complains about Class2 being static. I don't know how a non- static type is defined in F#, but you may need to change yours to that.

Comment: _"Wouldn’t it be nice if you could say dotnet dump and get a file like this?"_ - a file like _what_?

Comment: @Fildor A shell file that recreates the solution and lets you see everything at once.  (I edied that last sentence to clarify.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are declaring a module `Class2` inside `LibraryF` and only inside this module, you have a class `Class2`. F# modules are compiled as static classes and so if you open `LibraryF`, the `Class2` refers to the static class representing the module.

You can resolve this by dropping the module declaration from the F# library (you would only need a module if you also wanted to have top-level let bindings such as functions or global values, but if you do not need those, you can put the class directly inside a namespace):

```
namespace LibraryF
open LibraryC

type Class2() =     
  inherit Class1()
    
  member this.Junk() = "not static"
  override this.Number = 42
  override this.Greeting() =
    let fromBase = base.Greeting()
    $"{fromBase} from Class2 {this.Number}"
```